# I want to change Result of PL/SQL Query (ROW to Column)

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

This is existing result of PL/SQL Query :

| Module ID | Module Name | Generation | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IGen3 | 3 | 2002 |
| 2 | IGen4 | 4 | 2003 |

What I needed as attached Image :

[image]

```
Module ID   |  1     | 2
Module Name |  IGen3 | IGen4
Generation  |  3     | 4
Year        |  2002  | 2003
```

I tried concept of Pivot but I am beginner, I couldn't able to arrive solution. Please help me with the solution.

Comment: If you are using PL/SQL why have you tagged SQL Server, which uses T-SQL.

Comment: Sorry, Edited the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can consecutively use `UNPIVOT` and then `UNION ALL` clauses such as

```
WITH t1 AS
(
 SELECT Module_ID AS m_id, -- keep this one as numeric
        TO_CHAR(Module_ID) AS Module_ID, 
        Module_Name, 
        TO_CHAR(Generation) AS Generation,
        TO_CHAR(Year) AS Year
   FROM t -- your table
), t2 AS
(  
 SELECT *
   FROM t1
UNPIVOT (
         val FOR col IN (                           
                          Module_ID,
                          Module_Name,
                          Generation,
                          Year
                        )
        )
)
SELECT col,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m_id = 1 THEN val END) AS val1, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN m_id = 2 THEN val END) AS val2
  FROM t2
 GROUP BY col
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/X4t8gsAR)</kbd>